# Вычислить 2^n

Tags: c++

Дано натуральное число n. Вычислить 2^n

Comment: @кристина, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Разрешаю, вычисляйте.

Comment: Вот формула: 2 << n

Comment: @кристина, я понимаю когда сюда приходят люди и говорят про задачу с нахождением наиболее оптимального пути, например. Но не сообразить, как подручными средствами возвести число в натуральую степень - это сродни вступлению в секту сайентологов.

Comment: @Janycz, 1 << n

Comment: Надеюсь девушка не на пограммиста учится :)), просто программирование у нее общеобразовательный предмет...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Знаковый оператор сдвига влево <<
Все биты смещаются влево. Число справа дополняется нулем. Операция используется для быстрого умножения на 2

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned long n = 0;
    unsigned long result = 0;
    cout << "Enter n: ";
    cin >> n;
    result = 1 << n; 
    cout << "2^n = " << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В условии дано _натуральное_ число, а не _натуральное, меньшее 64_. Для чисел, больших 64, ваш подход неверен.

Comment: @VladD, согласен. Думаю, если бы речь шла о больших числах, то это было бы определено в условиях задачи. Иначе же можно запутать человека излишней реализацией вычисления степени > 64. Если Вы максималист, то пожалуйста продемонстрируйте решение. В таком случае ответы будут исчерпывающими.

Comment: @vilsh: писать полностью корректное решение влом, сорри. Например, можно явно воспользоваться длинной арифметикой[.](https://gmplib.org/) Или просто выдать ошибку, если результат не помещается в свой тип (unsigned long в вашем случае).

Comment: Ну, если 2^n, то это в любом случае просто. Надо только договориться о порядке бит а оооочень длииииинном двоичном числе.

Вообще же, что-то в таком духе.

    char *verylongbin = (char *)calloc(n / 8 + 1, 1);
    if (verylongbin)
      verylongbin[n / 8] |= 1 << (n % 8);  // оп-па! 1-ка в нужном месте.
    else 
      perror("calloc");

Правда, для получения `perror("calloc")`, а не SIGKILL от ядра (зависит от текущих лимитов) возможно придется поиграться с `getrlimit()/setrlimit()`.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с ф-цией **pow**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned long n = 0;
    cout << "Enter n: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "2^n = " << pow(2, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не `math`, а `cmath`

Comment: А если результат выходит за диапазон double? А где обработка ошибок?

Comment: mikillskegg - зависит от среды.
VladD - Дано _"натуральное"_ число n

Comment: @woopy, стандарт - cmath. Или уж в крайнем случае math.h. Если даже где-то и подходит имеется специфический хедер math (кстати, где?), то поскольку в вопросе конкретная среда и компилятор не указаны, то следует придерживаться стандарта или указывать среду отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Млин, а чё нельзя написать в лоб без извращений со сдвигом (типа круто) и применения math (типа из пушки по воробьям)?

```
long result=1;
for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
  result=2*result;
```

По крайней мере код будет работать безотносительно n и разрядности и проч. битовой муйни. Ну разве что есть опасность переполнения

Comment: Все правильно. Только вариант со сдвигом работает намного быстрее, а проблема остается - ограниченность вместимости long.

Comment: @mikillskegg этот вариант может быть предпочтительнее в случае именно с этой девушкой - наверняка это задачка из института, и если она продемонстрирует преподу манипуляции со сдвигами, то этот вариант скорее всего не будет принят. Ну а вообще бурные обсуждения этого вопроса выглядят несколько странно - ТС наверняка уже забыла об этом своем вопросе

Comment: @DreamChild, тоже правильно.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, ну, при таком подходе, уж растолковали бы девушке, что такое степень числа, тогда про цикл может она сама догадается.